# No password prompt returned to stdout when running script with nodejs' child_process.spwan(..)

Tags: node.js, child-process, flyway

I'm trying to create a utility that will squash flyway migrates. If I provide a password to the flyway conf file (so that no prompt is made), then the process runs as expected, however, in the case when a prompt for the flyway command *should* be generated (Which would consist of the text "`Database password:`"), then none is generated and a error for attempting to connect without a password is generated.

```
const child_process = require("child_process");
const os = require("os");

.
.
.

//Problem code below

let flywayMigrate = function(dbpassword){
  return new Promise(function(){
    let child = child_process.spawn(                              
      "./flyway",                                      
      ["migrate"],                                     
      {                                                
        cwd : "/home/admin/flyway"                     
      }
    );
    child.stdout.on("data", function(data){
      let out = data.toString();
      console.log(out);
      //containsString(haystack, needle) being a utility method
      if(containsString(out, "Database password:")){
        child.stdin.write(dbpassword);
        child.stdin.write(os.EOL);
      }
    });
    child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
      console.log(data.toString());
      reject();
    });
    child.on("exit", function(){
      console.log("child process finished");
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Does anybody know what's up?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working, but I think even if entering the password on promt worked it wouldn't be ideal.  The flyway cli supports passing in the password as part as the ENV which is cleaner https://flywaydb.org/documentation/envvars

Comment: @generalhenry thank you, that is the approach i ended up using, but I still wish I could figure out what was going on here!

Comment: It's possible that flyway only runs interactively when given a tty give https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty a try